# magento2 how to change product price while change the value of text field?

Tags: magento2, price

Hi i would like to change my product price dynamically while change the custom option **text field** value.

I have written the code as shown below

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml

<script>
require(["jquery","Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils"],
function(jQuery,priceUtils) {
var finalPrice=500;
var formatedPrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(finalPrice);
jQuery('span.price-final_price > span.price-wrapper >span.price').text(formatedPrice); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Can you write details with sample?

Comment: @Rana ji also i have tried like this also  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157713/magento-2-custom-product-price-want-to-change-using-jquery

Comment: I am not sure if this can help https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply gaurav Jain. Actually. I have installed the mageworx custom options extension. And trying to do the customization according to our client requirment in the frontend view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution The below script has been written in the template file (wrapper.phtml)

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml


    <script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils','jquery/ui'], function ($,priceUtils) 
    {
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.CabWidth').on('change', function(){ 

        var finalPrice='200.55';
        formatedPrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(parseFloat(finalPrice));
        jQuery('span.price-final_price > span.price-wrapper > span.price').text(formatedPrice);
        finalPrice=(pricePerText*textObjects)+(pricePerImage*imageObjects);
        formatedPrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(parseFloat(finalPrice));
        jQuery('span.price-final_price > span.price-wrapper > span.price').text(formatedPrice);    

        });
    });

    });
    </script>
```

**Note**: Magento2rootFolder/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js copied and pasted to below path

```
Magento2rootFolder/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js
```

Comment: What is pricePerText and pricePerImage in your code?