# Customise price in product collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, product-collection, magento2-enterprise

I am working on Magento 2 and having issue with price.

I want to customise the product price. I did it via plugin and it's working fine on product page and list page.

As we are using a plugin, it is not overriding the price in collection with custom price. Due to this price filter is also not working according to updated product price. As we are using price slider-Min - Max price is also not correct.

**I have debugged a lot and here is my findings**

**Min-max price is calculating from product collection by using following methods.**

> **$productCollection->getMinPrice();**
>
> **$productCollection->getMaxPrice();**

Product collections we are getting on product list page is not including the customised price. I think, if we set customised price to product collection then price thing will work fine.

Here is plugin which I am using to customise price.

**1.etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice">
    <plugin name="product_price_change"
            type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Updateprice"
            sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**2.Plugin/Updateprice.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin;

class Updateprice
{
    public function afterGetValue(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice $subject, $result) {
        
        return $result + $myCustomPriceCharges;

    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is reason behind changing price logic? Could you please tell me what is business requirements?

Comment: I want to add extra charges into product price according to attribute value.

Comment: Hello @Pramod , If you have any idea Please share.

Comment: @PramodKharade : Reason could be anything. Why are you asking for business requirements instead providing solutions ?

Comment: @ChanderShekhar : I am also facing the same issue. Please post the answer once get the solutions.

Comment: Price is more complex than it seems
- Prices are indexed to improve performance.
- Not all entities that work with Price get it from the Product entity so this is not a simple Plugin solution.
- At any time the price could be retrieved directly from the db or from the index.
- Even when you manage to change the price display in one particular part (e.g listing) you will still have inconsistencies across the board.
- Messing with prices might hurt other functionality like special price, tier price etc.
Do not mess with PRICE unless you really have to and you know what your are doing

Comment: @Vulpea - According to you there is no way to achieve such functionality ? I simply want to add custom charges in product price. I have used di.xml and it is working fine except price filter on product detail page as mention in this question.

Comment: Don't Know why, If Magento provide this functionality ( override ) then it should be work every where with in Collection too.

Comment: It depends how important is this for you and how much is your client prepared to invest. When messing with price there is a lot to take into consideration. Discounts, Taxes, Indexing, Orders, Quote etc. I would certainly look at alternatives and mess with price logic as a last resort and if the client is prepared to invest the hours. You should ask for other opinions. Preferably from someone who worked with price before. Filters use another collection see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208230/magento-2-where-code-are-the-filters-from-the-layered-navigation-applied-to-th

Comment: totally agree with @Vulpea, price is way too complex for some quick hack to work, you will end up with more problems

Answer (score 1):

You are right the functions `getMinPrice()` and `getMaxPrice` in  `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` class will need to be updated to include the custom charges.

You can write your own implementation of those methods by utilizing di.xml. However, I suspect you will have to implement codes to change the behaviors of more classes to make this work entirely (I don't know for sure but likely that the indexers class).

Also, consider how promotional rules work with your setup. Tax calculation is another area to look into.

Alternatively, I'd suggest that you make your price **inclusive** of customs charges. In your template, you can display the product price as the + custom charge amount (presumably the customs charge is stored in a product attribute).

So for example if product A price is $80 + $20. It is easier to store A's price as $100 and modify your template to display:

```
$priceBefore = $product->getPrice() - $product->getCustomCharge();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your Idea. Custom change is adding to product dynamically.

Comment: if you can let us know a bit more about the  business application maybe we can suggest something

Comment: Everything is already explained in Question. We just need to add some custom charges into product price on frontend every where in collection too. Please Share your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add in di.xml

```
<config>
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="change_product" type=" Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product " />
  </type>
</config>
```

create file in Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        customPrice=10;  
        return $result*$customPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for update @Birjitsinh, I have also tried this but issue is still persist. If you have any other idea Please share.

Comment: Hi check this link you want to check like this?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157909/magento2-how-to-change-product-price-while-change-the-value-of-text-field

Comment: OR you can use Marketting->promotions->"catalog price rules"

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to adjust the layered navigation price filter **and all your products have the extra custom charge**, you can create a plugin to add your custom charge to the `getMinPrice()` and `getMaxPrice()` methods.

You do that the same way you added it to the regular price.

> .../etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <plugin name="adjust_collection_min_max_price" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</type>
```

> .../Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product;
class Collection
{
    public function afterGetMinPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $result) {

        return $result + $myCustomPriceCharges;

    }

    public function afterGetMaxPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $result) {

        return $result + $myCustomPriceCharges;

    }
}
```

If only some of your products have the extra charge, then the above won't work correctly for products that don't have the charge.

In this case you should consider alternative approaches instead of plugins.

For example: Catalog -> Products -> Custom Options -> Add a required option that adds the extra charge only to products that should have your extra charge.

Comment: It is showing correctly in navigation but when you use to filter, filter collection is not working fine.

Comment: Are you using an extension for layered navigation? Is yes, which one? If you're using Mageplaza's Layered navigation (as I am), you will most probably have to add your custom charge to one of the JS files, for example in my case would be `/web/js/price/slider.js` or `/web/js/view/layer.js`. If you have another extension, you would need to check it's JS files and figure it out (I'd search for something like "min", "max", "updatePrice" inside the JS files).